# MDX function for counting year on year difference

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to come up with function to count year-to-year difference in sales ([Measures].[Castska]), the following does not work as expected:

`CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].year_to_year_sales
 AS ParallelPeriod([D_Time_YM].[Year],1,[Measures].[Castka]),
VISIBLE = 1 ;`

Comment: When asking a question, you should identify the diffrent Dimension and their level and hierarchies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expression is wrong. I am supposing that "D_Time_YM].[Year]" is a userhierarchy and it has a level "[Year]" in it. Based on this assumption use the code below.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].year_to_year_sales
 AS 
(ParallelPeriod([D_Time_YM].[Year].[Year],1,[D_Time_YM].[Year].currentmember),
[Measures].[Castka])
```